# How to hide a folder using programmatically in android, and access there file.

Tags: java, android

I am developing android application which having some external files. I want to hide these files. Can we access hidden file in my app. Example I have many of images which will be use in my app. I want to hide these file but access only using my app.

Comment: create a folder with dot ex. .images....it will be hidden

Answer (score 15):

Just put a `.` in front of your folder name than it becomes a hidden folder

Comment: will those images be visible in my mobile gallery? @Rohit

Comment: Yes when you set visible hidden folder from settings

Comment: please give an upvote on this question i got banned from asking questions . @Rohit

Answer (score 11):

Android is multi user linux system, so if you create folder starting with `dot`, it'll be hidden.

So store folder starting with `dot`

for example

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ".hiddenFolder");
folder.mkdir();
```

and store all images in this folder and access images in your app from same folder.

Comment: great...close the question then if satisfied with the answer.

Comment: Some devices allow to access hidden folders (starting with ".") like I have HTC Desire 820 q phone which allows me to access hidden folders. If you don't want to allow access to users then this solution may not work.

Comment: there are apps which are used to access phone storage with hidden folder access,  if you want to prevent it, then encrypt the folder and decrypt it while using app..

Answer (score 2):

Create a folder with a . (dot) before its name, and add an empty .nomedia file inside it. (.(dot)nomedia - exactly as I typed it) and add your files ands images there.

Now other Apps like Gallery will ignore these images. That's the only way that I think this can be done.

E.g.: folder name: .images

which includes an empty file .nomedia