# how can I prevent the user from accessing the dedicated directory of app in android

Tags: java, android, encryption, directory, hide

I am encrypting some data and transfer it to the dedicated directory of my application and now I want to know how can I prevent the user from accessing that folder??
Is it possible to hide it ??

thank you!

Comment: The following link might answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36124082/how-to-hide-a-folder-using-programmatically-in-android-and-access-there-file

Comment: Store it in internal storage, such as `getFilesDir()` on `Context`.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use shared preferences or database to store data is better but you can store your data in folder starting with dot to hide it.

For example
`File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), ".hidden"); folder.mkdir();`